# add static ressource to template filter function

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I want to dynamically add icons from my static dir when using a template tag, but I do not want to add them in the templates HTML, but using a filter:

```
{% for field in form %}
        <td>{{ field|format_ }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

and `format_` looking like this:

```
@register.filter(name = "format_")
def format_(field):
    if field.widget_type == "clearablefile":
        f = f"""{field}<button class="btn btn-danger"><img src="{{% static 'images/x-square.svg' %}}"></button>"""
        return mark_safe(f)
    return field
```

I tried it with the same syntax I would use in the template, but just escaped: `<img src="{{% static 'images/x-square.svg' %}}">` which just shows exactly that in clear text, not the icon on the template. What is the correct way here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `static` function like this:

```
# Older Django <3.0 (also deprecated in 2.0):
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

# Django 3.0+
from django.templatetags.static import static

iconUrl = static('images/x-square.svg')
```

Your code will be:

```
@register.filter(name = "format_")
def format_(field):
    if field.widget_type == "clearablefile":
        iconUrl = static('images/x-square.svg')
        f = f"""{field}<button class="btn btn-danger"><img src="{iconUrl}"></button>"""
        return mark_safe(f)
    return field
```

Comment: works like a charm thanks a lot - one additional question though: does this work with JS files too? Can I populate the template with a little script like this?

Comment: yes, it works with all static files (images, css file, Js files ..)